# HTML button submitting form

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function which changes some fields on a form, I have two buttons one to call javascript function, and the other submits the form. Problem is the button to call javascript function submits the form. I have tried changing button type to "button", which brakes the button and it does not work.

```
 $("#button1").click(function () {

        //$("#usernameField").attr("value","");
        //$("#passwordField").attr("value","");


        if (authType == 0) {

            $("#usernameLabel").hide();
            $("#usernameField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

            $("#passwordLabel").hide();
            $("#passwordField").hide().find('input:text').val("");

            //$("#initialCatalogLabel").show();
            //$("#initialCatalogField").show();

            document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "Intergrated";
            $('#authType').val(1);


        }
        else {

            $("#usernameLabel").show();
            $("#usernameField").show();
            $("#passwordLabel").show();
            $("#passwordField").show();
            //$("#initialCatalogLabel").hide();
            //$("#initialCatalogField").hide();

            document.getElementById("button1").textContent = "SQL Authentication";
            $('#authType').val(0);
            //return false;

        }


<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<fieldset>
    <legend>connection</legend>
   <div class="editor-label">
       Authentication Type
   </div>
   <div>
      <button id="button1" value="Intergrated" name="intergrated">SQL Authentication</button>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        Connection Name
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.conName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.conName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
       Data Source
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dataSource)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dataSource)
    </div>
     <div class="editor-label" id="initialCatalogLabel">
       Initial Catalog
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="initialCatalogField"> 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.initialCatalog) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.initialCatalog)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label" id = "usernameLabel">
       Username
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id="usernameField">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" id = "passwordLabel">
       Password
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" id = "passwordField">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="authType" id="authType" value="@Model.authType" />
    </div>


   <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
        @{
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.error))
{
                <div style="color:Red">
                   @ViewBag.error 
                </div>           
}
        }
    </p>

</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the form, not the button

No need to use `e.preventDefault();` when using jquery.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you try targeting the form?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: Did you say $('form').submit or $('#button').click ? I only ask because I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="button" id="button1" value="Integrated" />
```

Maybe the wrong type of button you tried?